# Android Developer Console : how to select devices on Android version

Tags: android, google-play, android-market-filtering

I published an app to Google Play, but some of my users are unable to find it using their device.

The min apk for the app is 11 (Android 3.0).

When someone uses for example a Samsung Galaxy SII with Android 4.0, the app can't be found because the initial release of the SII was with Android 2.3. With a SIII it's no problem.

In the developer console, the console automatically checks to see which devices are compatible when uploading the apk. As developer, I can disable devices for download, but not enable devices.

Does Google Play check the current version on the device or does it uses the versio, of initial release?

How can I reach as many as possible devices? When I lower my min APK in the manifest, I get compilation errors.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

That's a really good question. Lowering your minSdkVersion or publishing multiple APKs is the best solution to reach many devices, your problem with this approach is that probably you are using some API features that aren't present in older APIs so that's why you're having compilation problems.

http://developer.android.com/google/play/filters.html#manifest-filters says:

> Example: 
>   The manifest includes **uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="3"**, and the
>   app uses APIs that were introduced in API Level 3. A user is searching
>   for apps on a device that has API Level 2. Result: Google Play will
>   not show the app to the user.

So I assume google will filter based on the current API version.
Can you post your app link?

Comment: [Link to my app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=be.lengo.autikoken.lite&hl=en)

Comment: It says it's not available in my country. Another good way to reach all devices (in the world ^^) is publishing worldwide